# Return columns from identified in List<string> in linq select clause at runtime

Tags: c#, linq

I have looked at Dynamic linq but I am obviously missing something.

I am attempting to import files from one system to another. I have a DataTable loaded from an Excel sheet containing file information. (ExcelDataTable). I also have a HastSet of files that the user would like to import. (FilesToImport). The user selects which information he would like to import from the speadsheet, and those columns are dynamic and selected at runtime. (List VariablesToUpdate). I am joining on my ID in the query but I am not sure how to return the required columns from the datatable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var query =
    from excelRow in this.ExcelDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    join file in this.FilesToImport.AsEnumerable()
    on excelRow.Field<Guid>("ceGuid") equals file.SourceFileIdentifier
    select dt.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    <COMPLETELY LOST HERE>
    , false);
query.CopyToDataTable();
```

I can work it out if I know what I would like to return using something like;

```
select new { ImportSourceFilePath = excelRow.Field<string>(filePathColumn)};
```

but like I said my columns will vary and I won't know until runtime what they are.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you select *all* the fields back as a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then have another LINQ statement that selects out only the fields you actually need?

Comment: I took your advice and ran with it. I didn't use a Dictionary, I simply used the DataRow from the query collection.

Comment: You should post your code as an answer and then mark it as the accepted answer so your question doesn't remain unanswered and other people can benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing;

```
var foundExcelRows =
from excelRow in this.ExcelDataTable.AsEnumerable()
join file in this.FilesToImport.AsEnumerable()
on excelRow.Field<Guid>("ceGuid") equals file.SourceFileIdentifier
select excelRow;

for (int i = 0; i < foundExcelRows.Count(); i++)
{
    DataRow row = foundExcelRows.ElementAt(i);
    // work with this row since I know the columns I expect   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) for your implementation.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx) is a little tutorial for `ExpandoObject`